# $x(x-1)^2+\alpha$ bifurcation diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, bifurcation

I have to find all the equilibrium points of $$\dot{x}=x(x-1)^2+\alpha$$ and sketch the corresponding bifurcation diagram, but I don't see how to start, since [the roots of this polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5Bx%28x-1%29%5E2%2B%5C%5BAlpha%5D%3D%3D0%2Cx%5D&lang=es) don't have 'nice' expressions. Do you know how to deal with this kind of systems?

Comment: The derivative is quadratic and does not depend on $α$. From that you can compute the bifurcation points and their nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$ f_\alpha(x)=x(x-1)^2+\alpha. $$
Then $f_\alpha'(x)=3x^2-4x+1$ has two roots $x=1,x=\frac13$. In order to find a bifurcation value of $\alpha$, let either $f_\alpha(1)=0$ or $f_\alpha(\frac13)=0$. So $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=-\frac{8}{27}$. Therefore the DE
$$ \dot{x}=f_\alpha(x)$$
has two bifurcation values $\alpha=0$, $\alpha=-\frac{8}{27}$. The bifurcation diagram is the following
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Using the graph of the RHS function (e.g. see https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ia9fmlfbo9) one can argue qualitatively for which values of $a$ how many equilibrium points there are and what their behaviours are.

Comment: Ok, I can argue using the discriminant of the cubic formula, which in our case is $\Delta=-\alpha(4+27\alpha)$, and determine the number of roots based on its sign, but how could I classify the equilibrium points?

Comment: The approach I'm suggesting does not require the use of the discriminant, but sure. For the classification of eq. points one can look at how the sign of the RHS changes.